# How to fix error message "UNITY NO INTERNET CONNECTION. CANNOT FETCH ORGANIZATION"?

Tags: error-handling, create-react-app

[image: Error message]

I installed UNITY. While creating a new project I get an error:

> NO INTERNET CONNECTION. CANNOT FETCH ORGANIZATION

I do have an internet connection; I can search and log in to my account, but it displays the error message.

I tried basic troubleshooting like restarting my laptop and trying to connect and disconnect to internet but it still the same. I thought I have installed it incorrectly, but I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can try with based on my experiencec:

- Sometimes, firewall or antivirus software can block Unity from accessing the internet. Please make sure that Unity and Unity Hub are allowed through your firewall and that your antivirus is not blocking these applications
- If you use proxy, Unity might not automatically detect and use your proxy settings. You may need to manually config your proxy settings for Unity or Unity Hub.
- Sometimes, your DNS cache might become outdated or corrupted, this will also cause the connection issue.
- You can try changing your DNS Servers to Google's Public DNS (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) or Cloudflare's DNS (1.1.1.1).
- Also please make sure that you are using latest version of Unity Hub
- You can try running Unity hub as an administrator.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hiii, I tried turning off my fire wall. It still not fixes the issue. Thanks, thought!